# Minimum time to sleep to ensure sleep occures regardless of clock cycle?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-sleep

I know clock cycles vary between operating systems and settings.  If I am writing code that wants to be relatively confident (at least 95% sure) of a sleep occurring what is the minimum time I could use for a sleep and be confident that any computer/os running the code will sleep?

Is there a way to gaurente a sleep of at least one 'clock cycle' regardless of how long that cycle is in java?

Comment: `Thread.sleep` _guaratees_ to sleep for **at least** as long as specified (except for spurious wake ups). It's just not guaranteed to sleep for _only_ that long. General rule of thumb is that granularity is around 15ms.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Don't spurious wake ups happen only with `wait()`?

Comment: First, what do you mean by "sleep" exactly? It's not clear what it is you want to ensure. Second, it would extremely helpful to understand your objective here.

Comment: I second what @DavidSchwartz said.  If you want to sleep for the smallest possible amount of time, then why not sleep(0)?  In fact, why sleep at all?  If you think you need to sleep(), then chances are very likely that you are either re-inventing a wheel (e.g., `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, `javax.swing.Timer`, ...), or else you are making a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never try doing that. Ask yourself if you really need to sleep for one clock cycle. Tying your implementation with timers is always a bad decision. Below I give you a few alternatives.

### Use a mechanism similar to fps in games implementation

A number of libs already implement the concept of fps. Usually their implementation already abstract away clocks per second and OSes limitations/details. You could use that concept and be platform agnostic.

This way you can tweak your time requirement by using more or less fps.

### Use a mutex.

Why do you need to sleep for one cycle? That is a very small amount of time. You could try to synchronize (if that is the case) using mutexes instead of timers.

Also, mutexes are usually implemented by hardware instructions. So that guarantees they are atomic. If you really need to sleep for an infinitesimal time, you could lock the mutex and then unlock it. To be honest, any code you execute will by definition (unless it is a NOOP) be similar to sleeping by one cycle. You could also use `tmp = 1+1`. That takes two instructions.

I suggest the mutex. From your question, it is not clear why you need that sleep time.

### Mutex with user interaction

If you need to wait for user interaction (or any external event, like requests), lock the mutex and only unlock it when the event or user input becomes available.

### Derive the timer value

If you really wanna go down the timer road, I suggest you implement a routine that executes a long for loop and then you can try to derive your timer from the time it took to run through that for loop.

As I said earlier, I don't find this approach to be reliable but it is something. Also, I suggest that you also protect this code using a mix of Monte Carlo reliability techniques and unit tests. You can read more about this on [this article](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~briank/BrianKorverMonteCarlo.pdf).

As a final note, beware the optimizations that the compiler/interpreter can make and screw your timer.